# Close of the accordion when click once again in the head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to althern the open and close of a some accordions from Django Data, the data shows correctly, when I click another element the rest of accordions close, its ok, but when I click again in the same head of this accordion, this one not close just return open once again.

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-head', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var value = $(this).children().children().attr("id");
    $("#paquete").val("Paquete seleccionado: " + value);

    $('.accordion-head').children().removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion-head').children().children().children().removeClass(' iluminar');
    $('.accordion-body').slideUp();
    $('.accordion-head .pull-right').html('+');
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    $(this).children().addClass('active');
    $(this).children().children().children().addClass(' iluminar');
    $(this).children().children().children().children().html('-');
    return false;
});
```

I desire that when I click in the head of the open body, the body close, and the head return to first class color (just for example, the initial color was green and after then orange).

example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lycz9k13/)

Comment: Can you provide your code (with html) inside a simple fiddle?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev sure, let me do it

Comment: The link are in the description now, thankss @N'Bayramberdiyev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the accordion you clicked has class `active` using [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method. Here is the updated code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-head', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var value = $(this).children().children().attr("id");
    $("#paquete").val("Paquete seleccionado: " + value);

    $(this).children('a.iluminar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.accordion-head h3').removeClass('iluminar');
    $('.accordion-head .pull-right').html('+');
    $('.accordion-body').slideUp();

    if ($(this).children('a.iluminar').hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).find('h3').addClass('iluminar');
        $(this).find('.pull-right').html('-');
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn4u8wvr/1) based on your code.

I hope this works as you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution @N'Bayramberdiyev !!